# Can't sign commits with git

Tags: git, gnupg

I'm trying to set up git to sign all of my commits. GPG works fine for me by itself, as does git. However, when I enable commit signing in git, it doesn't work at all and throws this error:

```
can't read "old_author": no such variable
can't read "old_author": no such variable
    while executing
"commit_author_reset $old_author"
    (procedure "commit_committree" line 66)
    invoked from within
"commit_committree file9 c7498b3c51335cb1ae453588aa44d7fc442d5b9f .git/GITGUI_EDITMSG"
```

I have the following config values set in git:

```
commit.gpgsign=true
gpg.program=gpg
user.signingkey=XXXXXXXX
```

Comment: What is the exact command you typed in to sign the commit?

Comment: @rlee827 I use git gui and just click commit. However, committing from the command line using `git commit -m "test"` also fails with the less descriptive 
"error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object"

Comment: Which part of the GPG key ID did you put under `user.signingkey`?

Comment: @rlee827 first 8 digits of fingerprint

Comment: I had the similar error and the reason was the key expired.
You may need to regenerate the key. Maybe it should be reported in git to fix the message.